# SFML 2.1 Code::Blocks Static linking not working,

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, sfml

I am new to the idea of linking libraries in c++, and am trying to get SFML to work with C++. I am on Windows 7 64-bit and am using Code Blocks. I have downloaded the 32-bit mingw GCC SFML DW2 version of SFML. I followed this tutorial: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-cb.php to set up code blocks. I am staticly linking the libraries. When I press the "Build" button, I get whole host of errors, with undefined reference to '__Unwind_Resume' and '__gxx_personality_v0'. I have looked up this issue, and have only found command line fixes, using g++ instead of gcc. I cannot do this within the codeblocks UI. Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: I just did this recently. Easy to miss part of setup: "...If you want to get rid of these DLLs and have SFML directly integrated to your executable, you must link to the static version. Static SFML libraries have the "-s" suffix: "sfml-xxx-s-d" for Debug, and "sfml-xxx-s" for Release." Make sure you are using those "...s..." versions.

Comment: @Conduit I'm pretty sure I did. Under Project->Build Options->Linker settings I have sfml-graphics-s-d etc. for debug and sfml-graphics-s etc. for release. Is there something I missed?

Comment: The only other things I can think of off the top of my head are the order in which the libraries are added (from first to last in the list: audio, network, graphics, window, system) and the define for SFML_STATIC in compiler settings...

Comment: OP is correct that he has somehow to specify that he need to use `g++` instead of `gcc` as **linker**. I don't know code::blocks well enough to point you in the right direction though.

Comment: Yeah thx. I did define SFML_Static, and I am almost 100% sure I have the right order, although I will try to reverse it.

Comment: Can confirm they were in the right order

Comment: Out of ideas until I have access to my setup, then... guess I'll leave this one to the pros. Hope you get it figured out!

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @pqnet um the mingw I don't know much information other than that I downloaded the mingw version from the codeblocks website

Comment: was it `codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe` or `codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe`?

Comment: looking at ny downloads history, I think it was the first of those

Comment: from what I can read on the tutorial you linked, if you are using the default mingw shipped with code::blocks you should use the GCC `4.7 TDM (SJLJ) - 32 bits` version of SFML (the red square at beginning of the page), not the mingw one

Comment: Ok so I did that but with the 64 bit options and it told me I have an undefined reference to sf::String::String(const char*) and loads of similar errors

Comment: no, get the 32bit one. The compiler shipped with `code::blocks` is 32-bit, so it probably won't work with 64-bit code

Comment: It worked! One step closer to a greater understanding :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the compiler shipped with `code::blocks` is the 32-bit 4.7 TDM-SJLJ one, so you need the version of SFML compiled with the same compiler (`GCC 4.7 TDM (SJLJ) - 32 bits`)

If you want to use the 64-bit version of the library you need to install the 64-bit version of the compiler, available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/TDM-GCC%20Installer/Previous/1.1006.0/)

Answer (score 1):

change the linker program in settings->compiler->toolchains to g++.exe or mingw-g++.exe

Comment: even if it this time the problem was different, this answer may be useful to someone who find this page from Google.